# How to avoid redirecting to SSL port

Tags: web-applications, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat6, web.xml

My Web.xml config in my SSL confugured web app(deployed on tomcat(8080 port)) is as follows

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I tried https://google.com, I am getting the page
When I tried **http://google.com**, it automatically redirects to https://google.com:8443. So I am not getting the page.

I want it to be redirect to https://google.com instead of https://google.com:8443.

Kindly help me. Will let u know if u need any further details.

Comment: Example given as google.com since it not allowed me to add a dummy domain name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it.
Removed SSL redirectPort from server.xml of tomcat

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

like,

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

Comment: So you are now redirecting to an HTTPS connector on port 443?

Comment: @EJP Now it redirects to HTTPS://localhost/ instead of HTTPS://localhost:8443/

Comment: Actually it redirects you to https://localhost:443. As this is the default https port, this will not be shown by the browser. If your server.xml defines an https connector on 8443 (or anything else besides 443) this will still not work.